# How to define datatype to match the data length?

Tags: sql

I need to create a new table include some sharepath (e.g. `\\network\sharespace\test1`), 
To avoid query results follow some blank spaces after the path(e.g. I cann't accept `\\network\sharespace\test1__________`like this),I need to set its datatype to match the path length. How could I do? could anybody help to to set this?

Comment: You might get better answers if people know what SQL server you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your language lack a chomp function?

You can use the `VARCHAR` type to produce a string field of a given length; however, unless your sharepaths are all going to be the same length, you'll still end up with the same problem, so it's time to return to chomp.

Answer (score 1):

SQL 101 for beginners: use a variable length data type (varchar). Then go on and read the documentation about all data types your particular sql server language dialect supports.